Want to get current time and current time - 24 hours in AWS Step Functions / EventBridge Scheduler
I'm doing an incremental export from DynamoDB to S3, and I want the window for the export to be the last 24 hours.
I have seen that many people are suggesting to use a Lambda to do this, but I was curious if there is any native way to get this done in Step Functions or EventBridge Scheduler.
I tried using the "Pass" node in Step Functions to get the current time, and then using something like this:
    "exportFromTime.$": "States.Format('{}T{}Z', 
States.JsonToString($.currentTime).split('T')[0], 
States.JsonToString($.currentTime).split('T')[1].split(':')[0]-24)"

But this just gave me an error of, must be valid JSONPath or a valid intrinsic function call.

Can you confirm what you want to see in exportFromTime property? I want to confirm before I answer.

@JustinCallison, sure so I want to get a 24 hour window to give to my incremental export, so for example:
exportFromTime: 2024-11-04T00:00:00Z
exportToTime: 2024-11-05T00:00:00Z
I'd want to get these times dynamically everyday when the event bridge schedule / rule triggers the step function

There isn't currently a reasonable way to do this directly in the Step Functions workflow. Step Functions has a number of Intrinsic Functions as well as the Context Object that you technically could use to do this. However, it would be super complicated when you need to consider month roll-overs etc. So I suspect you are better off to write a simple Lambda function to provide this.
That said, this is feedback we hear often (need for more date/time manipulation in the workflow logic), so it's something I'd like to see us provide a better solution for in the future.
